# The space $V^{0}_{p}$ of p times covariant tensors and canonical isomorphisms

Tags: tensors, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra

I have been studying tensor calculus by myself, but I have found the following claim in my book:

> The space $V^{0}_{p}=V^{*} \otimes \cdots \otimes V^{*}$ of $p$ times covariant tensors is canonically isomorphic to the space $\mathcal{L}_{p}(V)$ of $p$-linear forms over $V$, i.e. this isomorphism maps the tensor product $f^{1} \otimes \cdots \otimes f^{p} \in V^{0}_{p}$ of linear forms $f^{i} \in V^{*}$ to the usual product $f^{1} \cdot f^{2} \cdots f^{p} \in \mathcal{L}_{p}(V)$, which is defined by $(f^{1} \cdot f^{2} \cdots f^{p})(v_{1},v_{2},\ldots,v_{p}) = f^{1}(v_{1}) \cdot f^{2}(v_{2}) \cdots f^{p}(v_{p})$. Schematically:
>   $$\mathcal{L}_{p}(V) \to V^{*} \otimes \cdots \otimes V^{*}$$
>   $$f^{1} \cdot f^{2} \cdots f^{p} \to f^{1} \otimes f^{2} \otimes \cdots \otimes f^{p}$$

I tried to understand this with an example, but I wasn't able to get it. I would appreciate any help!

Comment: what in particular is most confusing about what you wrote? The $p$-linear forms take values in the field so the product of $f^1$ through $f^p$ is simply the multiplication of field-valued functions (probably $\mathbb{R}$). On the other hand, the tensor product is an abstract way of multiplying vector spaces to make new vector spaces. For some books, the isomorphism you mention is used to define $\otimes$.

Comment: Maybe you could add the half-understood example you mention, I might be able to help you with that...

Comment: maybe looking at rank two your heuristics should rise: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1047994/tensors-of-rank-two-in-physics-and-mathematics/1058209#1058209